# Default background color of Theme.AppCompat.Light android

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme

What is the color code (hex) Android System use if windowBackground set to null as follows for parent theme **Theme.AppCompat.Light**

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
```

Can anyone help me to know the exact hexa code?

Answer (score 9):

It uses

```
<color name="material_grey_50">#fffafafa</color>
```

as described in the theme `Platform.AppCompat.Light`. This value is for `appcompat-v7:23.4.0` and might differ on other versions.

Answer (score 3):

If you set `android:windowBackground` to null then you're not going to get default colour from parent theme. You're actually overriding this to be null, which means nothing's going to be painted as your window background. If your layouts don't cover the window completely with their own backgrounds then you're going to see random artifacts.

In other words [Avoid Null Window Backgrounds](https://medium.com/google-developers/developing-for-android-viii-e91ced595fac#.d4nt4c989).

Answer (score 1):

@null means no background at all (View.getBackground() returns null).
It means you want to remove the background.

These are related QA:
[is there any diff @null Vs #00000000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311123/is-there-any-diff-null-vs-00000000)
[Set Background as null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155198/set-background-as-null)
[How to have a transparent ImageButton: Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402787/how-to-have-a-transparent-imagebutton-android)
[How can I specify a null as an XML attribute for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042395/how-can-i-specify-a-null-as-an-xml-attribute-for-android)